What are these dark spots on my hydrangeas?
I have hydrangeas that have dark (and one has a milky looking spot) spots on the leaves.
Can you tell me what they are (or from) and how to rid the hydrangea of them?
I live in the Northeast.  It's been hot.  I water every other day.





The dark spots on your hydrangea leaves are likely indicative of a fungal infection, with Cercospora leaf spot being a common culprit. This disease manifests as small, circular spots with tan or grey centres encircled by brown or purple halos, typically appearing on the lower leaves and progressing upwards.
The milky-looking spot you've observed may suggest the presence of powdery mildew, another fungal issue that presents as a white or grey powdery coating on the foliage.
Both of these fungal diseases thrive in warm, humid conditions and are often exacerbated by overhead watering, which keeps the foliage wet and facilitates the spread of spores.
Management and Prevention:

Watering Practices: Adjust your watering routine to focus on the base of the plant, avoiding wetting the leaves. Watering in the early morning allows any moisture on the foliage to dry quickly, reducing the likelihood of fungal infections.

Air Circulation: Ensure adequate spacing between plants and consider selective pruning to improve air flow through the hydrangea. Enhanced air circulation helps foliage dry faster and diminishes the humid conditions that fungi favour.

Sanitation: Promptly remove and dispose of affected leaves to prevent the spread of the disease. Clearing fallen debris from around the plant also reduces sources of fungal spores.

Mulching: Apply a fresh layer of mulch beneath the plant after removing diseased leaves. This can help prevent soil-borne spores from splashing onto the foliage during watering or rainfall.

Fungicidal Treatment: If the infection is severe, consider applying a fungicide labelled for use on hydrangeas. Products containing chlorothalonil or thiophanate-methyl are effective against Cercospora leaf spot. Always follow the manufacturer's instructions regarding application rates and safety precautions.


By implementing these practices, you can manage the current infection and reduce the risk of future occurrences, promoting the health and beauty of your hydrangeas.
I hope I was able to help you. :)
